# Google App Engine - Remove custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I have used a custom domain for one project on Google App Engine.
Now I want to use the same domain for another project, but I can't remove it from the first project.

I just get the message:

> Only domain owners are permitted to remove an assignment

I now that on several times I was able to delete custom domains before.

Is there anything I forgot to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, somehow I had to go through the domain activation process again.

Probably because I thought that I would only need the DNS TXT-Property for the activation process and deleted it directly after.

Now I had to go to the SSL-Panel and there is a link to domain activation on the top.
After I readded the DNS TXT-Property I can now delete the custom domain.

Comment: OK, to soon, now I can click the delete button.

But after I click nothing happens and the request get's a HTTP 405, like in my other problem [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/812261)

Comment: OK, so I couldn't delete them because of this error, but I could move them by adding them to the new project and on the warning that I'm using the same domain on two projects I was able to choose only use in new project.